# Have we ever seen a shaved or a bald Wookiee?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

This (disturbing?) image was [posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/8ceh3d/what_chewbacca_would_look_like_as_a_shaved_man/) with the title ***"What Chewbacca would look like as a shaved man."***:

[image: Chewbacca as a shaved man]

[This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/8ceh3d/what_chewbacca_would_look_like_as_a_shaved_man/dxedlc5/) claims:

> this was made by texturing his base model in Battlefront II(2017) with human skin tones-so it is exactly what he would look like under that fur if he had human skin.

At any rate:

## Have we ever encountered a depiction of a Wookiee who is shaved or bald?

I think we'll be relying on lower levels of canon here, but it must be at least of higher canonicity than merely fan-made material.

Comment: Suggestions for tags?

Comment: [star-wars-legends], because I'll be shocked if something like this is in Disney Canon.

Comment: There were bald wookie representations in 2015 (Buzzfeed, and a couple other sites), but not what you are going for.

Comment: Thanks for giving me nightmares with bald Wookies...

Comment: There's some basis for it. Terran animals can suffer from alopecia, resulting in loss of body hair. Chimpanzees look similar, but the musculature is a lot more evident. Bears just look weird. https://www.belgraviacentre.com/blog/the-case-of-guru-the-chimp-and-animal-alopecia/

Comment: ^_^ And http://www.thedailymash.co.uk/news/arts-entertainment/new-star-wars-features-shaved-chewbacca-20171213140938

Comment: I hope not!  Yuck!

Comment: That can't be an image of **shaved** Chewbacca. He would have fair follicles dotting his face and head and neck. There is a big difference between a depilated Wookie and an epilated one.

Comment: Who has seen shaved Wookies? Doctors and nurses during Wookie surgery. Kinksters with bareskin fetishes watching Wookie porn. Angsty emo teen wookie trying to upset their parents.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, we have never seen a hairless Wookiee.

However, when designing the [Stereb](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stereb) species, writer John Jackson Miller described them as "big hairless wookiee guys," perhaps giving us a hint at what that might look like. It bares a striking resemblance to the fan-made depiction.

[image]